# Shortest path from source to destination with constraints on the order of vertices traversed

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Suppose that the we have a bidirectional graph with V amount of vertices and E amount of edges, where all of the edges' weight are 1. Now, every vertices bar the source has its own level and suppose that we want to reach level L. Suppose that we start from level 1. When our level is i, we can only pass through the vertices that are either level 0 or level i. After passing a vertex that has level i, we level up by 1.

Now, given a starting point and a target level, how do we compute the minimum steps (costs) needed to reach the target level?

I believe that this problem can be solved with modified BFS algorithm. As of now, I can determine whether such path(s) exist(s) or not but I haven't been successful on computing the costs.

Any help and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For example, let's have a graph with V = 5, E = 4, L = 3, and starting point at vertex 0.
The following lines are the level of each vertex:

0 NO-LEVEL

1 0

2 0

3 2

4 1

and these following E lines represent the edges:

0 1

1 2

2 3

0 4

With this input, the output should be: 5 (0->4->0->1->2->3).
However, my code's output is 3 (0->1->2->3).

I am still confused on how to include the 0->4->0 process when counting the distance.

Comment: When we are at level 5 for example, can we pass a vertex at level 3 or 4 as well, or we should only pass vertices exactly at level 0 and 5?

Comment: We should only pass vertices with either level 0 or 5. Note that each vertex might has the same level too. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest making L copies of every vertex. Vertex (v,i) means vertex v "at" level i. Then set the edge costs equal to infinity if we cannot go from (v,i) to (w,j). For example, if vertex v has level 3 and vertex w has level 2, then the cost from (v,3) to (w,2) is infinity.

Then solve a standard [shortest path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) on the resulting network.

Comment: Simple and efficient. Given the very simple constraints on the order, I'd suggest going for this method rather than for the general one, the regular language constrained shortest path algorithm, which is .... hum .... much much harder.